# Value cannot be null: Parameter: Source error received from JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance, jmeter-3.2

I have been receiving this error message on particular request - "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source".

My Scenario is that 1 user will be transacting 5 transaction (Search and Remit). I'm targeting to run 650 Users to 3250 Transaction. The problem is that one particular request which is getting details from the DB, some data is passed but mostly are the mentioned error message above.

I Have 2 CSV Config, 1 from Users, the 2nd is for the Data where the second csv is inside the Loop Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your application tells you that the request is not correct, it expects a value and you're failing to provide the value. Use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) to validate the values of the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are being sent for successful and not successful requests, it might be a test data issue, for example an extra comma in the CSV file will make CSV Data Set config "think" that this is the [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) for the next column.